# Youtube and ClouDinary

Tags: performance, google-api, cloudinary, vimeo-api

I am thinking to use youtube to store several videos that are private, and I will show them in my app too.

And what about ClouDinary Or Vimeo  are they good options?

Just want not to be surprised after. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for your problem, it is only according to what you prefer...

Some will be more youtube, some more vimeo.